# Json-server generates new password on any user property change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

I am using json-server and json-auth to mock backend of my react app. So i have a situation where i need to give a user status of "inactive". When i check db.json i can see that whenever a change of isActive property of user happens, encrypted password is being changed. So instead of my user getting error message that he is blocked he gets message that password is not correct. Is this normal behavior of json-server and json-auth and is there any workaround? I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is no solution yet: https://github.com/jeremyben/json-server-auth/issues/45